# Hive external table not returning anything although file is present in hdfs

Tags: hive, hdfs

I have an external table in hive, although the underlying file is present when I try to query the table the results are erratic as in sometimes I get proper rows and some times it returns 0 rows. My external table is stored in RC format and I am using Hive 0.11 version. Is there anyway I can find root cause or is there any known bug on similar lines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with hive metastore connectivity.